# Enabling Top navigation and side navigation in SharePoint 2019 new modern look - OnPremise

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-server

I am migrating a SharePoint 2013 on prem environment to a SharePoint 2019 on prem environment. Current 2013 site has a top nav and a side nav in a custom master page. Client would like to keep the new modern look. Is there a way get both navigations subsite/sitecollection nav and a top Nav with new modern look?

Comment: I figured it out: I had to activate publishing feature on Site feature and Sitecollection feature for Term store based Top Nav to show on parent site collection and subsites. Client now doesn't like the look of OOTB top navigation. Now I am looking for a custom top nav!

Answer (score 0):

Editing the masterpage is not an option in Modern, but you can get the top and left Nav to show up with the Modern Team site template, sts#3, the Communications site template will be missing the left NAV.

Answer (score 0):

In the sts#3 (Modern Team Site) you only have the left navigation. There is no top navigation in it.

I am researching now the same problem with the subscription edition. Looks like the only possiblitly to have a top and a side navigation is to create a SPFx Top or side Navigation.

Either like [this](https://github.com/tom-daly/spfx-side-navigation) on a modern communication site (will try this tomorrow)

Or create a top navigation like [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/global-navigation-in-modern-sharepoint-using-spfx-pnp-and-fluent/ba-p/2734875) on a modern team site

I think both are not really perfect.

Comment: Definitely, for SP 2019, you can develop custom top navigation using SPFx application customizer and if you want this in SP online, Microsoft is rolling out new navigation features for team sites, check [this blog](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/) for more details.

Comment: Yes, i saw this feature, but it still does not allow both top and side navigation. Also the question is when, if ever, this comes to on premise.